# Django model: How to avoid referencing the same record when using with 2 foreign keys from the same table

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-orm

I have two Django models that look like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...


class Game(models.Model):
    teamA = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='teamA')
    teamB = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='teamB')
    ....
```

`Game` model has 2 foreign keys to `Team` model.

Of course, it is not possible for a team to play against itself, so I would like to prevent teamA and teamB from referring to the same record in DB.

So you can't create a game like this:

```
Game.objects.create(teamA=ChicagoBulls, teamB=ChicagoBulls)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a constraint in the [**`.clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), and also at the database level with a [**`CheckConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) (not all databases will however enforce this):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import F, Q

class Game(models.Model):
    teamA = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='teamA')
    teamB = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='teamB')
    # …
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.teamA_id == self.teamB_id:
            raise ValidationError('The two teams should be different')
        super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=~Q(teamA=F('teamB')),
                name='different_teams'
            )
        ]
```

The `.clean()` method is *not* checked when you create an object with the model layer. It is however validated when you create a `Game` through a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

You probably also might want to make the `name` of the `Team` unique, such that there can not be two teams with the same name:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    # …
```